# Are there absolute value of field, which is not discrete in $\Bbb{R}_{＞0}^×$, and also not dense in $\Bbb{R}_{＞0}^×$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$  be a field with $\Bbb{Q}_p⊆K⊆\Bbb{C}_p$.
Are there absolute value of field, which is not discrete in $\Bbb{R}_{＞0}^×$, and also not dense in $\Bbb{R}_{＞0}^×$?

All values I know is dense or discrete in $\Bbb{R}_{＞0}^×$, if you know or find some values which is neither dense nor discrete, I really appreciated it, thank you.

P.S
　I assume $K$ to be $\Bbb{Q}_p⊆K⊆\Bbb{C}_p$

Comment: any subgroup of $\Bbb{R}_{＞0}^×$ is either discrete or dense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In fact, any subgroup $G$ of $(\Bbb{R}^+, \cdot) \cong (\Bbb{R},+)$ is either discrete or dense. Additionally, $G$ is dicrete if and only if it is finitely generated.